# How to customize Prometheus metrics http_client_requests generated by SpringBoot actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project based on SpringBoot 3.1.4 in microservice architecture. I use Declarative Rest Client:

```
public interface AccountsApi {
    @HttpExchange(
        method = "GET",
        value = "/accounts",
        accept = {"application/json"}
    )
    ResponseEntity<List<Account>> accountsGetList(
        @RequestParam(value = "accounts", required = true) List<String> accs);
}
```

to sending request to another service:

```
ResponseEntity<List<Account>> responseEntity = accountsApi.accountsGetList(
                accountNumbers);
```

I am getting Prometheus metrics, generated by Actuator for every outcoming request:

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{client_name="localhost",error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/accounts"} 1.0
```

Since I have several clients I need to customize tags for this metric - add the name http client class, in this case something like **http_client="AccountsAPI"**

I find how to customize metric using customizer:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PrometheusConfiguration {

    class ExtendedClientRequestObservationConvention extends DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention {
        @Override
        public KeyValues getLowCardinalityKeyValues(ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
            return KeyValues.of(
//                    httpClient(context),
                    clientName(context), exception(context), method(context), outcome(context), status(context), uri(context)
            );
        }

        protected KeyValue httpClient(ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
            return KeyValue.of("http_client", getHttpClientClassName(context));
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public ExtendedClientRequestObservationConvention extendedClientRequestObservationConvention() {
        return new ExtendedClientRequestObservationConvention();
    }

    public String getHttpClientClassName(ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
        return ???????;
    }
}
```

But I can not find the way how to get class name of client?